# Setting up a loop curve with twisting method set to Z-up

Tags: mesh

How do I make a loop with a curve that has its twist method set to Z-up without having the mesh deform? The first image shows the problem, and the second image shows what I want. As you can see, setting the twist method to minimum fixes that part of the curve BUT the rest of the curve (see image 4) is a little tilted to the side and not levelled with the plane. I did selected everything and hit Clear Tilt, but that didn't work. I want the curve's twist method set to Z-up without having the end of the curve deformed (basically I want image 2 + image 3). How do I fix this?

File [here](https://pasteall.org/media/0/5/057100fc5b31bf81897d399be9ddcb1e.blend).

[image: Top part is deformed.]

[image: This is what I want it to look like but the curve is set to Minimum.]

[image: Levelled.]

[image: If you look closely it's a little tilted to the side.]

Comment: Hello please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here you go https://pasteall.org/media/0/5/057100fc5b31bf81897d399be9ddcb1e.blend @moonboots

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, I hope someone will know, the problem with Minimum seems unnoticeable to me, can you fix it with some vertices tilt?

Comment: Well in the meantime I can just apply the array and curve modifiers, then turn on snap to vertices and move that side in place. But I still would like a solution to this, still thank you for taking the time to help! :)